# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject Recording Lock

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

Does calling the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) Salesforce AMPscript function lock records in Salesforce when an update is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe it does.  Not sure it's documented anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so too, because it's updated through the connector user. But couldnt see any documentation either.